# How to solve the error return binascii.a2b_base64(s) binascii.Error: Incorrect padding?

Tags: python-3.x, base64, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, odoo-13

I got this error when I am creating excel file and csv file. The error shows in the line `purchase_id = self.env['purchase.excel.extended'].create(attach_files)`. How can I resolve the issue?

Below is my code:

```
for data in datas:       
            record = ';'.join(data)
            output.write(record)
            output.write("\n")
        data = base64.b64encode(bytes(output.getvalue(),"utf-8"))
        print('data', data)

        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            excel_file1 = ('/tmp/Purchase Report-' + str(datetime.today().date()) + '.xls')
            csv_file1 = ('/tmp/Purchase Report-' + str(datetime.today().date()) + '.csv')

        else:
            excel_file1 = ('Purchase Report-' + str(datetime.today().date()) + '.xls')
            csv_file1 = ('Purchase Report-' + str(datetime.today().date()) + '.csv')
            
        excel_file1 = excel_file1.split('/')[2]
        csv_file1 = csv_file1.split('/')[2]
        
        workbook.save(excel_file1)
        fp = open(excel_file1, "rb")
        file_data = fp.read()
        out = base64.encodestring(file_data)  
                                                    
# Files actions         
        attach_files = {
                'excel_file': excel_file1,
                'file_name': out,
                'csv_file': csv_file1,
                'file_names': data,
            } 
        print(attach_files, 'attach_files')
                      
        purchase_id = self.env['purchase.excel.extended'].create(attach_files)
        fp.close()
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'purchase.excel.extended',
            'res_id': purchase_id,
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'context': self.env.context,
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Comment: What error did you get?  Please edit your question and paste the traceback error into the question as if it were code

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the excel file name and the excel file content swapped. Similarly with the CSV file.

```
attach_files = {
                'excel_file': excel_file1,
                'file_name': out,
                'csv_file': csv_file1,
                'file_names': data,
            }
```

Should be:

```
attach_files = {
                'excel_file': out,
                'file_name': excel_file1,
                'csv_file': data,
                'file_names': csv_file1,
            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help. It really works

Comment: @TomMike: no problem. If you are happy that this answer is correct please consider upvoting and marking it as accepted.